# Append XML file to existing Access table

Tags: xml, ms-access, vba

I have an XML file I need to import into an Access table.  The XML file contains a Header with several fields, and a report body with a CDATA field containing repeating information (delimited text within the CDATA).  Here is the basic version of what it looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CMCFReport      
xsi:noNameSpaceSchemaLocation="CMCReports.xsd"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <HEADER>
      <ModeS>A5A1ED</ModeS>
      <TailNumber>UNKNOWN</TailNumber>
      <Timestamp>
         <Day>1</Day>
         <Month>12</Month>
         <Year>2016</Year>
         <Hour>18</Hour>
         <Minute>36</Minute>
         <Second>58</Second>
       </Timestamp>
   </HEADER>
   <ReportBody>
      <StorageReport>
         <![CDATA[PLF 01DEC16 1835 --------- L
COL3A-0072-001N BCG3F-CMCM-002K
MSG 2158513 01DEC16 1714 TO           A 1  
FDE 21500944 01DEC16 1713 TA           A
FDE 21502445 01DEC16 1713 TA           A
MSG 2158512 01DEC16 1714 TO           A 1
EOR
]]>
    </StorageReport>
  </ReportBody>
</CMCFReport>
```

When I run the import utility, Access tries to put the HEADER data and the REPORT body data into separate tables.  What is the VBA script for importing XML where you designate what field each item goes into?  This is as far as I've gotten so far:

```vb
Private Sub btn_Import_Click()
Dim StrFileName As String
   Dim fd As FileDialog
   Dim vrtSelectedItem As Variant
   Dim oDoc As MSXML2.DOMDocument60
   Set oDoc = New MSXML2.DOMDocument60
   Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
   With fd.InitialFileName = "c:\sample\*.xml"
        If .Show = -1 Then
            For Each vrtSelectedItem In .SelectedItems
                If oDoc.Load(vrtSelectedItem) Then
                    Dim oNodes As MSXML2.IXMLDOMNodeList
                    oNodes = oDoc.Nodes

                    Dim oNode As MSXML2.IXMLDOMNode
                    For Each oNode In oNodes 
                    'This is where I imagine the code would be to pull the relevant data out of each node and assign it to a field, I just don't know how to do that`
                    Next oNode
                End If

            Next vrtSelectedItem
        Else
        End If
    End With
    Set fd = Nothing
End Sub
```

I've never imported XML before, and I don't have the option of restructuring this XML, as I would be receiving a file from an outside source and importing it on a regular basis.  Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: Do you only want to import the CDATA in the report body (into an existing table)? How is the data delimited? Could you let us know how you expect the above XML to be parsed into the table structure you need?

Comment: I would like to import the items in the header nodes into their own fields, and then have those values repeat in front of the CDATA.  In my minds eye this is what the first row of data would look like, with each field marked out by a "/".  A5A1ED/UNKNOWN/1/12/2016/18/36/58/COL3A-0072-001N/BCG3F-CMCM-002K/MSG/2158513/01DEC16/1714/TO/A 1

Comment: Then the following row would be 

A5A1ED/UNKNOWN/1/12/2016/18/36/58/COL3A-0072-001N/BCG3F-CMCM-002K/FDE/21500944/01DEC16/1713/TA/A

Where the first 10 fields have repeated.

Comment: The data in the CDATA section is delimited by blank spaces

Answer (score 2):

*I don't have the option of restructuring this XML* ... actually you do with [XSLT](https://www.w3.org/Style/XSL/), the special purpose language designed to transform XML files and [MSXML](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/ms767600(v%3dvs.85)) can run XSLT 1.0 scripts.

Simply combine *HEADER* and *ReportBody* into one node, such as *REPORT* (which will be name of Access table). Then import this transformed XML with Access' [Application.ImportXML](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/access-vba/articles/application-importxml-method-access).

**XSLT** *(save as .xsl file, a special .xml file)*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                xsi:noNameSpaceSchemaLocation="CMCReports.xsd" 
                version="1.0">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="/*">
    <data>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="HEADER"/>
    </data>
  </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="HEADER|ReportBody">
        <REPORT>
            <xsl:copy-of select="ModeS|TailNumber"/>
            <xsl:copy-of select="Timestamp/*"/>
            <xsl:copy-of select="following-sibling::ReportBody/*"/>
        </REPORT>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

[XSLT Fiddle Demo](https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/pPqsHTr/1) *(see result in lower left)*

**VBA** *(separates file picker iteration and transform process, assumes all XMLs are same structure)*

```vb
Private Sub btn_Import_Click()
On Error GoTo ErrHandle
    Dim StrFileName As String
    Dim fd As FileDialog
    Dim vrtSelectedItem As Variant

    ' ITERATE THROUGH MULTIPLE FILE PICKER
    Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
    With fd.InitialFileName = "c:\sample\*.xml"
        If .Show = -1 Then
            For Each vrtSelectedItem In .SelectedItems
                ' TRANSFORM XML FILE
                StrFileName = CombineNodesXML(vrtSelectedItem)

                ' IMPORT TRANSFORMED XML (APPENDING TO EXISTING)                     
                Application.ImportXML StrFileName, acAppendData    
            Next vrtSelectedItem
        End If
    End With

ExitHandle:
    Set fd = Nothing
    Exit Sub

ErrHandle:
    Msgbox Err.Number & " - " & Err.Description, "RUNTIME ERROR", vbCritical
    Resume ExitHandle
End Sub

Public Function CombineNodesXML(xmlfile As Variant) As String
On Error GoTo ErrHandle
    Dim xmldoc As New MSXML2.DOMDocument, xslDoc As New MSXML2.DOMDocument, newDoc As New MSXML2.DOMDocument
    Dim outputfile As String         

    outputfile = Replace(xmlfile, ".xml", "_transformed.xml")

    ' LOAD XML AND XSL FILES
    xmlDoc.async = False
    xmlDoc.Load xmlfile

    xslDoc.async = False    
    xslDoc.Load "C:\Path\To\XSLT_Script.xml"        ' REPLACE WITH ABOVE XSLT PATH     

    ' TRANSFORM AND SAVE XML 
    xmldoc.transformNodeToObject xslDoc, newDoc
    newDoc.Save outputfile

    ' RETURN OUTPUT PATH
    CombineNodesXML = outputfile

ExitHandle:
    ' RELEASE OBJECTS
    Set xmlDoc = Nothing: Set xslDoc = Nothing: Set newDoc = Nothing
    Exit Function

ErrHandle:
    Msgbox Err.Number & " - " & Err.Description, "RUNTIME ERROR", vbCritical
    Resume ExitHandle
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, I will take a look at this later this evening; my government computer doesn't like the link to see how this looks.

Comment: Ok, I found a viewer to see what this would look like, all of the fields would import the way I want using this except the field containing the CDATA.  If I defined that node as a text object, could I then delimit it into different fields?

Comment: Correct, all nodes are on same level now to import into one table.

Comment: Trying the code you wrote, I'm getting a compile error for "TransformXML = outputfile" Argument not optional

Comment: Whoops! See edit should read `CombineNodesXML = outputfile`. I had changed the a function name since Access has a [TransformXML](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/access-vba/articles/application-transformxml-method-access) method.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this Monday when I'm back at my desk. I think you've got me most of the way to solving this.

Comment: Finally got a chance to get back into access and try this.  I was getting an error on the newdoc.save output file line, do I added  = " " and now I'm getting "The parameter is incorrect" on the Application.ImportXML StrFileName, acAppendData line

Comment: What is the error you get? Possibly *newDoc* is not a proper XML output. Are you sure XML files are same structure as what you posted? If any differ, transformation may not work.

Comment: I'm getting "Run-time error '-2147024809 (80070057)': The parameter is incorrect".  The outputfile seems to need a path defined afterwards, because when I add an = "c:\path\_transformed.xml" the error moves to the .ImportXML line on the first sub

Comment: Nope. `Save` is a method and not property so it is not assigning a value requiring `=`. I have added error handlers for a more informative message. Try importing just one XML and not many to test process. One again, I think the issue is your XML files are coming in as different format where XSLT is not transforming correctly, so *newDoc* is an empty object.

Answer (score 1):

While Zack has a point (you need to share a bit more if you want us to really help you), I can try to help you further along.

First, you need to turn `ValidateOnParse` on if you're going to parse that XML document without the xsd.

Then, you can iterate through all text nodes containing actual text by using the following XPATH query:

```
//*[string-length(normalize-space(text())) > 0]/text()
```

You will still have to fill in the specifics about how you're going to store this, but this should get you started. It gives you the node name and value for each node containing text.

You still have to add some logic for storing them in the appropriate fields in your table.

```vb
Public Sub btn_Import_Click()
   Dim StrFileName As String
   Dim fd As FileDialog
   Dim vrtSelectedItem As Variant
   Dim oDoc As MSXML2.DOMDocument60
   Set oDoc = New MSXML2.DOMDocument60
   oDoc.async = False
   oDoc.validateOnParse = True
   Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
   With fd
        .InitialFileName = "c:\sample\*.xml"
        If .Show = -1 Then
            For Each vrtSelectedItem In .selectedItems
                If oDoc.Load(vrtSelectedItem) Then
                    Dim textNodes As IXMLDOMNodeList
                    Set textNodes = oDoc.SelectNodes("//*[string-length(normalize-space(text())) > 0]/text()")
                    Dim l As Long
                    For l = 0 To textNodes.length - 1
                        Debug.Print textNodes(l).ParentNode.nodeName 'Node name
                        Debug.Print textNodes(l).NodeValue 'Node value
                    Next
                End If

            Next vrtSelectedItem
        Else
        End If
    End With
    Set fd = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: I did reply to zack with how I want to store this, at least with the initial thought I had.  Let's say I only need to extract the infomation in the CDATA <storagereport> section, and starting with "MSG" I wanted the fields be MSG, FAULT_CODE, REC_DATE, REC_TIME, PHASE, PRI_CODE, with each row delimited by spaces.  MSG, REC_DATE, and REC_TIME would have fixed lengths, while FAULT_CODE, PHASE, PRI_CODE, could vary between 7-10, 2-5, and 1-5 characters respectively.  It would be nice to have the fields in the header and the first row of the CDATA repeat in fields in front of each of those records

Comment: The _don't ask multibarreled questions_ message isn't really getting through, is it? As previously said, string splitting is a different task than parsing XML.

Comment: Well I apologize, responding to where you asked for more information as to how I wanted to store this data.  Without asking about splitting the string under <storagereport>, I am trying to store each of the text nodes in a separate field.  Parfait's transformation should make that fairly straightforward once I figure out the syntax to say "store <timestamp/day> into field name REC_DAY in tblFAULT_CODE".

Comment: I was finally able to try your code in the database I'm working on, I get an "unknown method" on the query string.  Was there something I needed to changed there? Sorry I'm pretty new to this.